# Set username/password in mosquitto

Tags: mosquitto

I have configured the [mosquitto configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OZwm.png)
 as shown in image
But still when i run broker , I am still able to connect client without any usename and passwd. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`#` is used to comment out things in the config file. Remove the `#` before the configs you have done and retry.